# Method [validateUserName] does not exist (Laravel 5)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My code is like this :

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'user_name' => 'required|user_name', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('user_name', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
                    ->withInput($request->only('user_name', 'remember'))
                    ->withErrors([
                        'user_name' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
                    ]);
    }
```

When I click button login, there is error message :

```
BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 2615: Method [validateUserName] does not exist.
```

Thank you

Comment: where did you extend the validator and add the user_name rule ? and what is the actual question ?

Comment: @lagbox, I am still confused. My previous login using email and it worked. Then I replace email with  username. After I replace with username, there is an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

**EDIT:** so you are trying to login using username/password combination instead of email/password combination?

add this to your Controller/Auth/AuthController.php

```
protected $username = 'user_name';
```

but you must switch back your postLogin method to

```
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);
```

Comment: I've marked. I just change like this : `$this->validate($request, [
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);`

Answer (score 0):

There is no validation rule `user_name`.

Unless you extended the validator and added that yourself it does not exist.

The available rules are here:

[Laravel 5.0 Docs - Validation - Available Rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#available-validation-rules)

`email` worked in your rules because `email` is an available validation rule you can use.

Comment: I think he is talking about email as login with email not as validation rule.

Comment: the error is clearly coming from the validator looking for a rule named 'user_name'.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I think what OP is trying to ask is how to login using username/password combination.

Comment: I assume the code was like this 'email' => 'required|email' so the OP changed it into 'user_name' => 'required|user_name' hoping that it will now look for username instead of email...

Comment: It is absolutely possible :) but until the OP provides an actual **`question`**, I am resolving the only error the OP is providing.

Comment: @Vojko I made the same assumption and acknowledged it above in the answer, if the OP extends there question to the auth side, you got that covered :-p

Comment: @Vojko, @lagbox, It's working. I just change like this : `$this->validate($request, [
            'user_name' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);`